# Problem with SIM800L

Tags: communication

I used a module SIM800L in my project. for power supply , I used LM2596 that is regulated on
4.2 volt.

Module connected perfectly and i tested sending "SMS" successfully.
but after approximately 30 minutes the message : "+CPIN: NOT READY" recieved from module.
The Response of module to the command " AT+CPIN?" is " SIM not inserted".
The strength of antenna is good.(AT+CSQ ==> 22)
I removed the SIM from the module and placed it on a mobile phone and used it about few hours.then
I removed SIM and placed it on SIM800L again , and after 30 minutes Communication failed again.
please guide me.

Comment: (1) "LM2596 that is regulated on 4.2 V". I usually use LM2596 stepping down 12V to 5V.